# how to write each [String] with writeFile into a File in haskell?

Tags: haskell, io

how can i write with writeFile a [String] into it?

e.g. i have `["one", "two", "three"]`

and i want to get into the file:

```
one two three
```

how to do this with haskell? i can write a additional function if needed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know of mapM? Do you know how to write a single string to a file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest to use the `unwords :: [String] -> String` instead of using `intersperse`. I would like to simply answer with the follwing simple example, using `ghci`:

```
Prelude> let ss = ["one", "two", "three"]
Prelude> writeFile "myfile" $ unwords ss
Prelude> readFile "myfile"
"one two three"
```

Answer (score 11):

This isn't to say anything `Tarrasch` and `prnr` haven't said, but the difficulty is arising from not separating IO from pure functions: You say

> I have `["one", "two", "three"]` and I want this into a file: `one two three`.

You have a list of strings, and want to do something, i.e. you are looking for a function `lkndfhu :: [String] -> IO ()`. True enough, but if you ask:

> What is the thing that I want to write to a (new) file?

you will notice that its the same sort of thing as in this case:

> What is the thing that I want to write to stdout?
>
> what is the thing I want to append to file file.txt?

Well, it's `"one two three" :: String`. You want something that maps `["one", "two", "three"]` to `"one two three"`, never mind what you are going to do with `"one two three"`

So really you are looking for a function `lkndfhu_pure :: [String] -> String` that you can compose with `putStrLn` or `writeFile filename` which are of type `String -> IO ()`

Well the prelude function `concat :: [String] -> String`, has the right type,  but it would yield `"onetwothree"` and the file or stdout would look thus:

> onetwothree

The Prelude function `unlines :: [String] -> String` has the right type, but would yield `"one\ntwo\nthree" and the file would look thus:

> one
> two
> three

The pre-given Prelude `[String] -> String` function you want is `unwords`, as `Tarrasch` notes; but as `pmr` notes `unwords` and `unlines` are both compositions of `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` with `intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]` -- basically:

```
 unwords mystrings = concat (intersperse " " mystrings)
 unlines mystrings = concat (intersperse "\n" mystrings)
```

or, equivalently,

```
 unwords  = concat . intersperse " " 
 unlines  = concat . intersperse "\n"
```

(These aren't the definitions actually used by the Prelude.) As `pmr` notes, the abstractness of `intersperse` means it can be used with `IO` in complex ways but there is no sign that this is what you need.  Note that `unwords` `unlines` and `intersperse` have variants for the fancier String-like types, e.g. `ByteString` and `Text`

If you want to think about document preparation that is consistent with using pure functions before passing to IO you might look at the pretty printing library that comes with the Haskell Platform (there are many others).  in ghci type `:m +Text.PrettyPrint`, then type :browse .  `ghci` (and `Hugs`) implement the `Doc` type in a special way, so evaluating an expression exhibits the `Doc` as it will appear to the reader if you render it to a string and write it to a file:

```
 PrettyPrint> let lknfdhu_strings = ["one", "two", "three"]
 PrettyPrint> :t lknfdhu_strings
 lknfdhu_strings :: [String]
 PrettyPrint> let lknfdhu = map text lknfdhu_strings
 PrettyPrint> :t lknfdhu
 lknfdhu :: [Doc]
 PrettyPrint> hcat lknfdhu
 onetwothree
 PrettyPrint> hsep lknfdhu
 one two three
 PrettyPrint> vcat lknfdhu
 one
 two
 three
 PrettyPrint> let looksGood = hsep lknfdhu
 PrettyPrint> :t render
 render :: Doc -> String
 PrettyPrint> render looksGood
 "one two three"
 PrettyPrint> render (vcat lknfdhu)
 "one\ntwo\nthree"
 PrettyPrint> let dash =  " - " 
 PrettyPrint> let dashdoc = text dash
 PrettyPrint> dash
 " - "
 PrettyPrint> dashdoc
  - 
 PrettyPrint> hcat ( punctuate dashdoc lknfdhu )
 one - two - three
 PrettyPrint> hcat ( punctuate (text "   ") lknfdhu )
 one   two   three
 PrettyPrint> writeFile "lknfdhu.txt" (render looksGood)
```

These examples are of course pretty primitive, check out all the crazy functions with `:browse` and the examples in the docs

Answer (score 4):

Use intersperse to get the spaces between the words and append every string in the list to the file at `path` where xs is your list of words:

```
mapM_ (appendFile path) (intersperse " " xs)
```

It probably is faster to flatten the list of strings and write it at once:

```
writeFile path (concat (intersperse " " xs))
```

Although the first feels more natural to me.

Edit: Please note that the first and second variant still do different things if the file already contains something. `writeFile` will simply write a new file while `appendFile` will append to the existing content. It isn't clear which behaviour you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned intercalate, which is the same as concat and intersperse.